# Python noob: "ImportError: No module named internet"

Tags: python, module, twisted

I'm trying to get Python twisted to work on my Ubuntu 11.04 box.

I did `sudo apt-get install python-twisted`

However, when I try the following code:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo()

reactor.listenTCP(1234, EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

I get this error which I cannot get to the bottom of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eamorr.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
  File "/home/eamorr/Desktop/twisted.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named internet
```

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Does [this answer help you?][1] Do you have a module named twisted (in your application) ?


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/161960/installed-python-module-is-not-found

Comment: This seems to work on my system . Try import twisted if it works ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is the name of your file. Python looks first in your current directory for modules. When you try to import `twisted.internet` it finds the file in your folder, which is called `twisted.py`. But there can not `internet` submodule be found. If you rename your file, Python will load the correct `twisted` and everything will be finde.

Comment: Hi, the file has now been called "eamorr.py" - I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: You probably still have a `twisted.pyc` file there. Remove that, too.

Comment: Ok, I got it working. Originally I had the file called twisted.py. I renamed the file, but I also had to delete `twisted.pyc`... Thanks so much for your help,

Comment: @ Tim Pietzcker: I also have same problem but where I can find the twisted.pyc file?

Comment: If twisted.pyc is anywhere (it may not have been generated) then it will be in the same folder as twisted.py. If it's not there, it shouldn't cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One can change the Python behavior to do absolute imports instead of relative imports.  Add the following to the top of the py file.

`from __future__ import absolute_import`